# AlarmManager is not repeating at the expected time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to start a service every a predefined time.
From my main activity I call SetAlarm method of a WakefulBroadcastReceiver with this code:

```
public class MyReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver  {
   public static final String PREFS = "Prefs";
   SharedPreferences mSettings;
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   Log.i("Receiver", "START");
   Intent service = new Intent(context, Awservice.class);
   startWakefulService(context, service);
}

public void SetAlarm(Context context)  {
   String Hour = getDuration(context, "PREFS_HOURS","0");
   String Min = getDuration(context, "PREFS_MINUTES","0");
   Long LHour = Long.parseLong(Hour);
   Long LMinutes = Long.parseLong(Min);
   Long time = (LHour*60+LMinutes)*60*1000;
   AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
   PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
   am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+time, time , pi);
}

public void CancelAlarm(Context context) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
   PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
   alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}

String getDuration(Context context, String value, String defaultValue) {
   SharedPreferences mSettings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
   return mSettings.getString(value, defaultValue).toString();
}
```

The problem is that my code works but is inaccurate.
e.g. If I set the activation time every 2 minutes the broadcast receiver doesn't work every 2 minutes but as follows:

```
21:32:52.068
21:33:27.842
21:36:38.258
21:37:59.437
21:39:42.178
21:41:30.643
21:43:27.898
21:45:42.199
```

What is wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you taking these times from?

Comment: Also, what version of Android are you running this on?

Comment: I take times from LogCat at Eclipse (these are from the Log.i("Receiver", "START"); command) and I run 4.4.2 but also I tested this on 4.3.

Comment: LogCat is a bad reference point for time. Who knows what time it's actually showing. For an accurate time use System.nanoTime();

Comment: If I set longer periods, like 10 minutes, it's easy to find out with a simple watch that my service starts about 3 minutes sooner or later than the expected time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On projects that have android:targetSdkVersion set to 19 the setRepeating() will not be exact. From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html):

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS
>   will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There
>   are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery
>   guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and
>   setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose
>   targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the
>   previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when
>   requested.

From CommonsWare's [Busy Coders guide](https://wares.commonsware.com/):

> The only way to get exact repeating would be to use setExact() and to
>   re-schedule the event yourself, rather than relying upon Android doing
>   that for you automatically. Ideally, you use setInexactRepeating(), to
>   help extend battery life.